# What's the bug in this reflection code?

Tags: java, reflection

My lack of Java is biting me on the heels again. I have the following member function:

```
protected void setData(Map<String, String[]> data) {
    Class thisClass = this.getClass();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String[]> item : data.entrySet()) {
        try {
            Field field = thisClass.getDeclaredField(item.getKey());
            try {
                if(field.getType().getName().equals("java.lang.Long")) {
                    // EXCEPTION HERE!!!
                    field.setLong(this, Long.valueOf(item.getValue()[0]) );
                }...
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // Skip this field...
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep on getting an IllegalArgumentException, and i don't fully understand why. Can anyone offer some insight?

The function takes a map, which it iterates, and assigns the values to "this" by checking if the field exists on "this" and if so, attempts to call `field.set()`.

Comment: Check the field.getType if it is the same as item.getValue().getClass()

Comment: Marcos, yes, they are the same, testing with java.lang.Long.

Comment: Check if the return value of item.getValue() is not null

Comment: show the stacktrace and exception message.

Comment: More detail on the error: Can not set java.lang.Long field za.co.mycompany.mypackage.model.User.id to (long)123

Comment: You should use the Wrapper Long instead of long

Comment: Post the enclosing class and all the member variables.

Comment: Marcos, I'm actually a PHP developer, so would you kindly mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: Is there perhaps a different way to initialize an instance of a class, using a Map object?

Comment: The question title is too broad and misleading (as to the final answer). Should be "what's my bug in this reflection based code."

Comment: This type of thing is so simple to do in PHP...

Comment: You should post the code for your User class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setLong(..)` tries to set a primitive value, and your fields is `java.lang.Long`. Always use the `set(..)` method for non-primitives. For primitives `getType().getName()` would return `int`, `long`, etc.

Initial answer: You need to make the field accessible: `field.setAccessible(true)`

Comment: Even when I call field.setAccessible(true), the exception is still thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Field.set() docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), you get an IllegalArgumentException if you try to set() a value into a field where the value isn't [assignable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) to the field.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, I only get illegal ARGUMENT exceptions - no illegal access exceptions:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Asdf2 {

    private Long long1;
    Long long2;
    protected Long long3;
    private long long4;
    Long long5;
    protected long long6;

    protected void setData(Map<String, String[]> data) {
        Class thisClass = this.getClass();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> item : data.entrySet()) {

            try {
                Field field = thisClass.getDeclaredField(item.getKey());

                try {

                    field.setAccessible(true);

                    if (field.getType().getName().equals("java.lang.Long")) {
                        field.setLong(this, Long.valueOf(item.getValue()[0]));
                    } else {
                        field.set(this, item.getValue()); // EXCEPTION HERE!!!
                    }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

                // Skip this field...
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Asdf2["
            + "long1=" + long1
            + ",long2=" + long2
            + ",long3=" + long3
            + ",long4=" + long4
            + ",long5=" + long5
            + ",long6=" + long6
            + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String[]> data = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        data.put("long1", new String[] { "1" });
        data.put("long2", new String[] { "2" });
        data.put("long3", new String[] { "3" });
        data.put("long4", new String[] { "4" });
        data.put("long5", new String[] { "5" });
        data.put("long6", new String[] { "6" });

        Asdf2 test = new Asdf2();
        test.setData(data);
        System.out.println(test);

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

My comments are:

1) If its a Long, you put the first element of the value (which is an array) into that field, but otherwise you put the entire array - that will only work if fields are also string arrays

2) You haven't posted the actual exception you get.  It might give more details?

3) You need to give us the "this" class - not just the set method - we need to at least see the field definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Which java version is the one you are using. Remember that autoboxing works over 5.0 version. According to the exception detail it seems that you are trying to assign a Long object value to a long (native) value. You could try this:

```
field.setLong(this, Long.valueOf(item.getValue()[0]).longValue());
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `field.set(this,Long.valueOf(item.getValue()[0]));` where `item.getValue()[0]` is a long value.